# Django app not showing registered models in Admin page

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-admin, django-migrations

I have tried everything I can think of and find on here but nothing seems to be able to get my models to register and show on my Django Admin page. Weird thing is I have another model that is already appearing on the Admin page that I've matched the syntax for but that one works and this other one does not.

models.py

```
class SimpleModel(models.Model):
    something = models.CharField('Simple Model', max_length=200, default='foobar')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

admin.py

```
from .models import SimpleModel

admin.site.register(SimpleModel)
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'bootstrap4',
    'app.apps.RequestsDashboardConfig',
    'applications_dashboard',
    'requests_dashboard',
    #'applications_dashboard.apps.ApplicationsDashboardConfig',
    'requests_dashboard.apps.RequestsDashboardConfig',
    #"app.requests_dashboard",
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

You can see I've even tried multiple variations of the INSTALLED_APPS but even this still does not work. I don't even get any errors when I start the server with this series of commands after deleting the migrations.

```
python3 manage.py flush
python3 manage.py makemigrations
python3 manage.py migrate
python3 manage.py createsuperuser
python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
```

I even tried deleting the entire DB, recreating it, and then running this again and still no luck!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where I went wrong in the end but for anyone who encounters similar issues to mine, I was able to solve this by doing another complete DB rebuild.